# Is there a way to reduce xcode build time using az pipeline caching?

Tags: caching, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, xcode5, continuous-deployment

I am currently using xcode built-in tasks and facing issue while caching and reducing its time.
I have already used caching in the same pipeline to reduce Cocoa Pods time too.

After successful caching of cocoa pods, /ios/ now includes Pods dir too but Xcode build still takes almost 30 mins

Answer (score 0):

We can [reduce build time using caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops). You need to find code that compiles slowly during the build process. Check if there are other parts which can be cached in the pipeline.

Basically, if it has the same behavior when building on your local developer machine, then I don't think there's a good way to reduce the build time in pipeline.

Reference the following threads to check that:

- [How to reduce Xcode build time?](https://medium.com/macoclock/how-to-reduce-xcode-build-time-e85f2af53a8f)
- [Caching CocoaPods on Azure DevOps Pipeline](https://medium.com/@zmoola22/caching-cocoapods-on-azure-devops-pipeline-3b1ed918b60e)

Comment: caching cocoa pods only reduces time of 'install pods'. Can you share the pipeline example here?

Comment: @TechStack No example here, you need to find out what's causing the build to be slow, it's all based on your code and build process. It's better to check it locally and see if the build is taking close to 30 minutes as well. If it has the same issue locally, then no way to address it in pipeline. If it's a specific issue in the pipeline, then you need to analyze the logs add see what's causing the build to be slow and see if there's a way to mitigate it.